# Reading huge json files

Tags: json, command-line-interface

I have a huge (1.2Gb) json files lookings like this, except that it is written as a single line:

```
[
 { data: [{ (json11) }, { (json12) }, { (json13) }, ... },
 { data: [{ (json21) }, { (json22) }, { (json23) }, ... },
 { data: [{ (json31) }, { (json32) }, { (json33) }, ... },
...
 { data: [{ (jsonN1) }, { (jsonN2) }, { (jsonN3) }, ... }
]
```

It is to big to be opened in a text editor and I couldn't manage to read it via `fs.readFile` in nodejs (I got this error:

```
buffer.js:194
      this.parent = new SlowBuffer(this.length);
                    ^
RangeError: length > kMaxLength
```

)

I'd like to read it to get all the json items in a separate files with on each line:

```
{ (json11) },
{ (json12) },
{ (json13) },
...
{ (json21) },
{ (json22) },
....
```

What is the easiest way to do this?